# Which string copying method is the faster in Delphi?

Tags: performance, delphi

I work in Delphi XE2 and I have to make a complicated function that sometimes copies longer parts of strings and sometimes only just characters. It depends on the content of the source string. So the question is that which example method is faster?

```
Len := Length(Str);
SetLength(Result, Len);
for I := 1 to Len do Result[I] := Str[I];
```

```
Len := Length(Str);
SetLength(Result, Len);
Move(Str[1], Result[1], Len * SizeOf(Char));
```

And I would be also curious how big is the difference in running time.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it right. If `Str` is the source string and you say 'copies ... parts of strings', I would expect beginning and ending character indexes. The two examples you present are easily tested by yourself, and you could also compare with simple assignment: `Result := Str` as that is what your example is doing. Will be interesting to see **your** results.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg These are just examples. Most of the time I don't have to copy the whole string just the parts of it. That's why I didn't write "Result := Str;"

Comment: So why do you then write example code, that does what you don't do mostly? :) I suggest you make your timing test yourself. If the results are unexpected, then you can return with actual meaningful code, sample data and results of your timing for an evaluation of what might be the reason, and how to improve.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I asked this question because I hope others have more knowledge about these different methods (copying a series of individual characters vs. using Move procedure) so they can give me an advice on which one should be used.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but there is a site dedicated to finding faster alternatives to Delphi RTL routines ([Delphi Fastcode](https://fastcode.sourceforge.net/) ). It's a bit dated, but should still work.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: The OP's code snippets are *not* equivalent to `Result := Str`. The OP's code snippets both result in a new string heap object with refcount 1, while `Result := Str` merely increases the refcount of the original `Str` heap object.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are right, otoh, I did not mean it literally, but in contrast to OP's description of the task to "copy ... parts of strings".

Comment: @MyICQ Afaik, Fastcode suggestions regarding strings have been included in Delphi already. Or at least, the Delphi RTL got improved otherways to be faster then back in the past!

Comment: Some have, but the world moved on since - there were many contributions that involved using SSE2 but obviously in 2007 or so that was still too new and not widely implemented by all CPUs so they were not taken. I have submitted a few improvements to core RTL functions in the the past year (such as FillChar) that use SSE2 which now can be taken as always supported which improved their performance significantly.

Answer (score 3):

The `Move()` alternative - even if `Move()` was written naively as a byte-by-byte loop (which it is not in the RTL, despite much room for optimization, which we might get soon(tm)) - would be faster, because for every indexed write to a `string`, the compiler inserts a call to `System._UniqueStringU()`.

To copy a part (if contiguous) of a `string` into a new `string`, I would probably use either `System.Copy()` or `System.SetString()` instead.

However, if performance matters, my intuition tells me that this part would probably not be the one worth optimizing, but rather to reduce `string` usage and copying parts of them as new `string`s. In .NET, that was the reason why they implemented `Span<T>`, which basically is a length restricted pointer. When dealing with things like `string` parsing, using such an approach boosts performance way more than optimizing the copying itself.

Bonus: If you write your loop like this, you omit the `_UniqueStringU()` call, because the `SetLength()` before already assured that `Result` is a string with `RefCount = 1`:

```
Len := Length(Str);
SetLength(Result, Len);
for I := 1 to Len do PChar(Pointer(Result))[I-1] := Str[I];
```

I am using a cast to `Pointer` first to avoid the `_UStrToPWChar()` call the compiler inserts when doing a `string` to `PChar` cast.

Comment: Thank you! For me, Move is better than System.Copy because I know the final length of the string in the beginning of the operation. So I can allocate the space for it with SetLength and after that I can move the substrings into it. If I would use System.Copy, each call would result in a new space allocation.

Comment: That is why I put "if contiguous" into parentheses. If you have multiple parts then `Copy` for multiple parts and then concatenate them again is clearly not the way to go.

Comment: @StefanGlienke in your final example, rather than using `PChar(Pointer(Result))[I-1]` inside the loop (which is just ugly to look at), I would first call `PChar(Result)` and save the pointer to a local variable `P`, and then use `P[I-1]` inside the loop. I might even be tempted to replace `Str[I]` with a pointer, too.